# How would toggling a bit in the POWCNT1 register cause hardware damage on the Nintendo DS?

Tags: hardware, nintendo-ds

From [GBATEK](https://www.problemkaputt.de/gbatek.htm#dspowercontrol), writes to a certain I/O port for power management may damage hardware:

```
4000304h - NDS9 - POWCNT1 - Graphics Power Control Register (R/W)
  0     Enable Flag for both LCDs (0=Disable) (Prohibited, see notes)
  1     2D Graphics Engine A      (0=Disable) (Ports 008h-05Fh, Pal 5000000h)
  2     3D Rendering Engine       (0=Disable) (Ports 320h-3FFh)
  3     3D Geometry Engine        (0=Disable) (Ports 400h-6FFh)
  4-8   Not used
  9     2D Graphics Engine B      (0=Disable) (Ports 1008h-105Fh, Pal 5000400h)
  10-14 Not used
  15    Display Swap (0=Send Display A to Lower Screen, 1=To Upper Screen)
  16-31 Not used
Use SwapBuffers command once after enabling Rendering/Geometry Engine.
Improper use of Bit0 may damage the hardware?
```

Emphasis mine. The document does not go into detail and provides no concrete information. How could improper use of the enable flag for LCDs cause hardware damage? Under what circumstances would it cause damage, and what types of damage to the hardware would it cause?

As pointed out in a comment, this may be similar to a [related issue](https://bgb.bircd.org/pandocs.htm#lcdcontrolregister) on the Game Boy:

> Stopping LCD operation (Bit 7 from 1 to 0) may be performed during V-Blank ONLY, disabeling the display outside of the V-Blank period may damage the hardware. This appears to be a serious issue, Nintendo is reported to reject any games that do not follow this rule.

<sup>I've posted this after writing a [meta question](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/984/8090) about the NDS and receiving the answer that it may finally count as retro.</sup>

Comment: It does seem interesting that they've written "improper use", implying that there may be some proper use for it.

Comment: Possibly enabling both at once would overload some part of the power supply chain. Or, it might exceed the fan-out of some chip trying to drive both at once, possibly corrupting other signals generated by the same chip with potential collateral damage to anything. IMO this needs circuit diagrams and data sheets to give a good answer. The power management page linked to by your link suggests the design is a bit fragile - e.g. look at the comment on issues with backlighting.

Comment: @alephzero As far as I know, there are no datasheets for the relevant parts. The NDS main processor is an ARM946E-S with custom display components that aren't public. However the author of the referenced document doesn't have access to any confidential information (as far as I am aware) but still wrote that improper use of the display enable bit may damage hardware.

Comment: @forest we can only speculate, but sometimes you find out the hard way that "improper use" of some bits in some registers can cause damage to the hardware: someone tried it, and the hardware was damaged. (This has actually happened to me, though with other hardware). And "improper use" usually means something like "you'll need to set up other things in other registers to make this work without damaging anything, but without documentation no one knows how".

Comment: An LCD does not like to be driven by DC, perhaps this bit switches off the AC generation.

Comment: Adding one to the guess pile: it needn't be an instantaneous problem. The concern might have been over unsafe patterns of enabling and disabling over time — e.g. doing so very quickly?

Comment: I wrote an email to the author of that document. He said that he wrote that because Nintendo states that that bit is "prohibited". He hasn't done any empirical testing but says that one could try to randomly toggle it on and off and see if it causes any damage or just temporary glitches.

Comment: Did some testing. If I toggle the bit fast enough (about 100 times in a second), it causes the system to crash. I think it also might lock up the ARM7 or something? Not sure, but the inputs sometimes fail (sometimes the touch screen, sometimes keys), and IPC to the ARM7 began to time out in the cases where it didn't cause the system to crash (black upper screen, magenta lower screen). No sign of hardware damage though, at least yet. My guess is it does not cause damage.

Comment: Another reply from the author of that document: _For trying to destroy something, I would try to disable LCD somewhere midframe outside of hblank/vblank, and keep it frozen on OFF state for a whole minute... maybe that could burn the currently drawn pixel? Though I hope that the LCD manufacturer and Nintendo did add some safeguards against that._ This might be interesting to test.

Comment: @thebusybee: Certainly that was an issue for passive screens, where only a portion of the screen would be driven at a time, and I know from experience that wrongly an early 1990s screen for an hour could cause DC-style degradation (which fortunately reversed itself over the next few hours, since the screen in question was on a brand new laptop just after such screens became available).

Comment: There's a similar warning for the Game Boy. http://bgb.bircd.org/pandocs.htm#lcdcontrolregister In the Game Boy Programming Manual, incorrectly disabling the display outside of Vblank causes a dark line to appear on the screen and is listed as a 'PROGRAMMING CAUTION'.